# How do I say 'It took me 4 hours to get to Hamburg' in Spanish?

Tags: traducción

How do I say 'It took me 4 hours to get to Hamburg' in Spanish?

> Tomó 4 horas volar a Hamburgo.

Any alternatives?

Comment: What is your specific doubt? Asking for a list of alternative translations isn't a very good format. If you have a specific doubt about your chosen translation, can you tell us what it is so we can help you with that doubt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I don't see anywhere on your sentence that you were flying, but rather only talking about how long it took you to get there, whether you were flying, driving or whatever, I don't see why you should add `volar` to your sentence.

A more correct approach would be:

```
Me tomó 4 horas llegar a Hamburgo.
```

The verb `llegar` simply states that you got there, instead of that you flew there.

Comment: Mh, the OP is translating the sentence as flying. You don't see anything related to fly?

Comment: Yeah, he said the sentence he was trying to translate was `It took me 4 hours to get to Hamburg`, which does not mention flying, I don't know why he chose to translate it as that in the first place though.

Comment: Well, the point isn't translating. Just helping with grammaṛ…

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it right:

> Me tomó cuatro horas volar a Hamburgo.

*Amburgo* is not Spanish, but Italian. I added an *H*.

As an alternative, you could say

> El vuelo a Hamburgo duró cuatro horas.

or

> Tardó cuatro horas el vuelo a Hamburgo.

All these sentences are somehow colorless, so you might want to add some color depending of your perspective. For instance, if you found the flight's duration was unnecessarily long you could say

> Después de cuatro horas *apenas* estaba en Hamburgo.

The opposite would be

> En cuatro horas *ya* estaba en Hamburgo.

Answer (score 0):

Me costó cuatro horas llegar a Hamburgo